# In WP 6.4.1 where is Ajax.googleapis.com called from?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In Wordpress 6.4.1 it appears that the most recent version of jQuery (3.7.1) is included in wp-includes>js>jquery. But my site is showing that the front end is loading 1.12.4 and it is apparently being loaded from Ajax.googleapis.com. I'm assuming a particular plugin is calling it from there. Is there a way to figure out which plugin would be loading jquery itself?

Comment: Search your codebase for `ajax.googleapis.com`. There are many ways to search files, from a text editor with directory support, to Terminal commands.

Comment: This isn't a coding question. Try a WordPress support site.